# When IHttpClientFactory close TCP connection internally?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

based on the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

```
// in startup.cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

// usage
public class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _remoteServiceBaseUrl;

    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Catalog> GetCatalogItems(int page, int take, int? brand, int? type)
    {
        var uri = API.Catalog.GetAllCatalogItems(_remoteServiceBaseUrl,
                                                 page, take, brand, type);

        var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);  // <------------------

        var catalog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalog>(responseString);
        return catalog;
    }
}
```

can I say after `await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri)`:

**A. The underlying TCP connection is not closed, no `FIN` packet has been sent to the server**

**B. After 5mins, the TCP connection will be closed, so `FIN` packet is sent to the server, but still there will be around 4 mins TIME_Wait period for it (twice the maximum segment lifetime which is 2mins by default), so the TCP connectio is actually closed after 9 mins?**

is my understanding on A and B correct?

Comment: The version of .NET that you're running on also matters, e.g. .NET Framework 4.8 will be using `HttpClientHandler` internally, which has different behaviour w.r.t underlying connections than `SocketsHttpHandler` (which is only available for .NET Core 2.1+).

Comment: TIME_WAIT occurs when both sides of the connection try to simultaneously close the connection.  TCP is reliable which means that every command gets an ACK.  When both sides close at same time on side does not get an ACK and remains half-open and half-close which is the TIME-WAIT Error.  Solution is only close connection from client and not server.

Comment: IHttpClientFactory doesn't close connections, it just reuses those HttpMessageHandlers. See [HttpClientFactoryOptions.HandlerLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.httpclientfactoryoptions.handlerlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: @shingo does it mean that  `IHttpClientFactory` will cache/remember the url in the reqauest , so when the same url is requested again, then the connection can be re-used?

Comment: Maybe it worths reading this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have more control about the underlying sockets' lifecycle then I would suggest to specify the [`PooledConnectionIdleTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.pooledconnectionidletimeout?view=net-8.0) and/or [`PooledConnectionLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.pooledconnectionlifetime?view=net-8.0#system-net-http-socketshttphandler-pooledconnectionlifetime) of the `SocketsHttpHandler`:

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(...),
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(...)
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> is my understanding on A and B correct?

Using a long-living `HttpClient` is different then using `HttpClientFactory` with short-living `HttpMessageHandler`s.

Your question is about the second case so, lets stick with that.

If you don't specify the `HandlerLifetime` then it will use 2 minutes as a default value. If you set it explicitly like you did via the `SetHandlerLifetime` then it will use that `TimeSpan` as the activity tracking period.

Inside the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` there is a method called [`CreateHandlerEntry`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L131) which will call the following method:

```
return new ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry(name, handler, scope, options.HandlerLifetime);
```

The [`ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry.cs) will use a simple timer to track the elapsed period without activity. It does **not** bother the handler directly.

Rather it allows to the callers of the `StartExpiryTimer` method to specify a `TimerCallback`. The `DefaultHttpClientFactory` passes the [`ExpiryTimer_Tick`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L193) delegate.

This method simply removes the handler from the active handlers and moves that into the expired handlers queue (there might be outstanding/pending requests still).

```
var active = (ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry)state!;
bool removed = _activeHandlers.TryRemove(active.Name, out Lazy<ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry>? found);
...

var expired = new ExpiredHandlerTrackingEntry(active);
_expiredHandlers.Enqueue(expired);
```

The `CleanupTimer_Tick` will take care of the expired handlers. It will `Dispose` the `ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry`'s `InnerHandler`, which is a marker class called `LifetimeTrackingHttpMessageHandler`.

Gladly that lengthy named handler receives the actual message handler as its constructor parameter. That received message handler is generated via a `HttpMessageHandlerBuilder` class. In case of the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` this will be the [`DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder.cs). That class uses the `HttpClientHandler` **not** the `SocketsHttpHandler` as its primary message handler.

Depending on the [`TARGET_BROWSER`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/77c5dbabc6c4b65580629cd7064a13d74ddf5a63/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs#L13C1-L19C10) the underlying handler will be either the `BrowserHttpHandler` or the `SocketsHttpHandler`

```
#if TARGET_BROWSER
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Metrics;
using HttpHandlerType = System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler;
#else
using HttpHandlerType = System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler;
#endif
```

...

My point here (as it was said by others in the comments section) is that the `HttpClientFactory` is at a much higher abstraction level than the actual TCP messages. If you search for `FIN` or `TIME_WAIT` messages then you will only find the [`tcp_fsm.h`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/51e70cbe57b55a898c93040b6f9c33b9fe0b6cdd/src/native/libs/System.Native/ios/netinet/tcp_fsm.h#L91).

My advice here is that if you really care about the TCP messages then use [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to scrunatize the underlying communication. It might require several experiments to see how certain method calls changes the underlying connection lifecycle.

Comment: is my understanding on A and B correct?

Comment: @user22155685 I've updated my post, please check it again.